# Complex number equation.

Tags: complex-analysis

How would i begin to solve this equation;

$z^7-2iz^4-iz^3-2=0$

I have just finished the nth roots of unity. 
So know how to solve equations like $z^3-125=0$ etc.

Comment: Factoring goes a long way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$
z^7-2iz^4-iz^3-2=z^4(z^3-2i)-i(z^3-2i)=(z^3-2i)(z^4-i)=0
$$
So, if you know how to find the $n^{th}$-roots of unity you have the solutions.

Comment: Should i have ended up with 7 possible solutions? Thanks

Comment: Yes , of course! ( foundamental theorem )

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can factor the polynomial by grouping.